# How would I convert a local image file to Base64 to POST to a custom API Endpoint?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, froala

I am working on a JavaScript library that is a rich text editor.  Currently, we can not `copy + paste` from a Word Document due to the clipboard being a local file and most browsers block the ability to read local files.  Our work around to this issue is to convert the local image file to a base-64, and using our local API, store the image on our servers so the img has a proper, hosted source.

The problem is this has to be handled entirely in JavaScript, which still is run in the browser and I can not see local files to be able to convert them:

[image: Screenshot of expected error]

This is currently the code I am trying to use, but can't seem to figure out a way to handle this entirely in JavaScript without using some time of File Loader from HTML.

```
function convertToBase64(){
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // Set up our request
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://uploadFileHere');
  //convert image to base64
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      callback(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  }; 
  //handle the response from Image API
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
        return xhr.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhr.send(base64String);
}
```

Is it possible to work around this issue or does my team and I have to come up with another solution?

**EDIT**:  Here is another rich text editor, where it IS possible to copy and paste images from Word, [Froala](https://codepen.io/Froala/pen/oZmGVP).  If this is not possible, how are they doing it?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to retrieve a file from the users machine and POST that to the server without the user selecting the file?

Comment: @LukeStoward that is correct.  They would (i guess) be selecting a file because it would be their own copy and paste from a text application, like Word, but they would not be physically choosing to upload the file via HTML

Comment: Not gonna happen.  As you yourself say, for security reasons, JavaScript on web pages cannot access any files.

Comment: @DanFarrell What would you suggest instead?  Is there a better practice of handling a situation like this or is it just an obscure way of handling our problem?

Comment: @DanFarrell Please see my updated question

Comment: Looking through your question, I'm not sure why you equate pasting from the clipboard with file access.  As long as the user pasted the content into your editor, you should have access to it.

Comment: @DanFarrell that is not the case when copying from word, it stores the image into a temp folder in the system, for whatever reason, which then makes it a local file in the eyes of Chrome

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That makes more sense.

Comment: @Rinktacular I have the same problem, did you find any solution